# Analyticity of a function at removable singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a confusion that at a removable singularity, a complex function f(z)  is analytic or not.

As lim f(z)= finite => f(z) has removable singularity.

Comment: See this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.

Comment: My Question is that at z=z0, limit of f(z) exist => z=z0 is removable singularity by definition 
but at z=z0, function has no problem i.e. function should be analytic at z=z0 without redefine  the function.